# DVR_PLAYER.exe reports Remote200.ocx is missing?

Tags: dvr, surveillance, home-surveillance

I have a program called DVR_PLAYER that is downloaded from a home security camera web interface.

The web interface saves surveillance footage in the form of proprietary .drv files.

I am unable to use the program to view the files on the cd on any machine that isn't the original machine I downloaded the files from.  Every time I try to open it up it says, "
Remote200.ocx not installed or it couldn't be installed. Please check user privilege."

I need other machines to be able to open and view the footage I've downloaded using this program so that I can hand it in to the local police. Any ideas?

Comment: Posting this question because of this comment in chat: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/982419#982419

Comment: Also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DVR_PLAYER software assumes that you've viewed the browser version of the software.  This is the fault of the original software designers.  Because the download link is provided on the web version of the site that requires ActiveX controls installed before it's viewed, they assumed it would be installed before you've downloaded the "standalone" software.

To get the DVR_PLAYER software to run on a machine that doesn't have access to the web version, you need to download and include both the missing Remote200.ocx and VideoViewer.ocx files.

To get these, you need to access the web version of the program and download the ActiveX controls. (You already did this if you downloaded the program to your computer).

Next, go to `C:\WINDOWS\Downloaded Program Files` and find Remote200 Control and CViewerControl Object.  Right clicking and selecting `properties` on both of these files will display their download location after CodeBase:

See the image below:

[image: Image of Remote200 Control Properties]

Browsing to those locations in IE will download you a couple of cab files:
RemoteWeb.cab and VideoViewer.cab  Just extract those to the DVR_PLAYER.exe directory, and you have a functioning playback program on any Windows computer, even one that doesn't have a network connection to install the ActiveX controls.

Note, if this still doesn't work, you need to make sure to run the DVR_PLAYER.exe as an Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to run the player software from an install disc instead of installing it. `.ocx` is a Windows ActiveX control. Typically controls are installed and registered with the system before they can be used by software.

Alternatively, you have installed it without administrator privileges, or it is software which requires admin privileges to run.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was a problem I kept running into and needed a solution I did some investigating. Yes it appears that you can download the DRV Player from DVR system and since you already have the ActiveX files it will run without issue. But if you send the video file to someone else they will be unable to run the file even if you send them the program files that you downloaded.

Solution: Visit the manufacture's website and download the player from there. I ran into this problem with our Speco Cameras and after downloading the player the videos work properly now.